# need to know when all async operation completed

Tags: reactjs

I have the following code:

```
callAPI() {
return this.myModel.map(action(retValue => {
      return this.myApi.doWork(retValue.Input).then(action(model => {
        this.model.Input = Object.assign({}, model);
        this.saveState();
      })).catch(error => {
        throw(error);
      });
    }));
```

if my client code I am doing something like this:

```
myStore.callAPI().then(() => {
      console.log("completed");
      this.setState({ loading: false });
    });
```

I am getting an error

> .then() is not a function

I want to get a callback when all async operations are completed.

Comment: Is this intentional? You have a curly brace inside your argument in the callAPI function.
`myStore.callAPI({)`

Comment: NO, I updated the post above

Comment: Does `Promise.all` not fit your needs?

Comment: `then` is not a function because it seems that you are returning an array (of unknown things to me). As Andrew said, you may want to use `Promise.all`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to await multiple promises and return the result which is another Promise which you can call `.then` on.
In order to always return a promise after an imperative block of code you can return [`Promise.resolve()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve) that will make the code chainable.

`callAPI() {
  return Promise.all(
    this.myModel.map(action(retValue => (
      this.myApi.doWork(retValue.Input).then(action(model => {
        this.model.Input = Object.assign({}, model);
        this.saveState();
        return Promise.resolve();
      }))
    )));
  );
}`

Please see an example:

```js
const sleep = timeout => new Promise(resolve => 
  setTimeout(() => resolve(timeout), timeout)
);

const tap = timeout => {
  console.log(`Task completed after ${timeout}ms`);
  return timeout;
}

const tasks = [
  sleep(1000),
  sleep(2000),
  sleep(500),
  sleep(30),
  sleep(2500),
  sleep(450)
].map(task => task.then(tap));

Promise.all(tasks).then(x => {
  console.log(x);
});
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure `this.myApi.doWork` is not a promise. That's his original error. You should mention that and wrap it in a `new Promise`

Comment: following Przemysław Zalewski code, I am getting all promises return immediately after the function is called, rather after the async comes back

Comment: Please add `Promise.resolve()` to always return (even an empty) Promise which you can then chain.

Comment: care to use my code as a basis for your answer, I dont think I am following your example.